# Too much horizontal space in an alignat environment

Tags: math-mode, spacing, amsmath, alignat, horizontal

I'm having a bit too much horizontal space in this MWE, and want a normal spacing:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{alignat}{2}
    \phi \quad &\Rightarrow \quad \tilde{\phi} &&= e^{-\, i q \vartheta} \, \phi, \\[1ex]
    A_{\mu} \quad &\Rightarrow \quad \tilde{A}_{\mu} &&= A_{\mu} + \partial_{\mu} \, \vartheta,
\end{alignat}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Here's a preview of the problem, shown in red:

[image]

I need the arrows and the equal signs to be aligned, and I want the same normal space on each sides of these symbols.  Currently, there's too much space after the `\phi` symbol.  How can I fix that without hacking (i.e. without adding phantom tricks)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can move the `&`'s.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{alignat}{2}
    \phi    \quad & \Rightarrow \quad & \tilde{\phi}    & = e^{-\, i q \vartheta} \, \phi, \\[1ex]
    A_{\mu} \quad & \Rightarrow \quad & \tilde{A}_{\mu} & = A_{\mu} + \partial_{\mu} \, \vartheta,
\end{alignat}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ow!  That was easy!  I didn't knew that we could move the & around like this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Move one of alignment signs `&` in front of the `\phi` and `A`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{alignat}{2}
    \phi \quad &\Rightarrow \quad &\tilde{\phi} &= e^{-\, i q \vartheta} \, \phi, \\[1ex]
    A_{\mu} \quad &\Rightarrow \quad &\tilde{A}_{\mu} &= A_{\mu} + \partial_{\mu} \, \vartheta,
\end{alignat}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That was very easy.  Thanks a lot!